# @ConfigurationProperties object returned null in spring boot application

Tags: spring-boot, properties-file

I have a config object which is mapped to the config file as below:

```
@Data
@Component
@ConfigurationProperties("app.cors")
public class DomainProperties {
    private Map<String, String> domainMap;
}
```

and my *application.properties* config file looks like:

```
app.cors.domainMap.local=localhost:8080
app.cors.domainMap.onlive=test.com
```

I am trying to read the values in the *domainMap* from the above properties file, to set them as Access-Control-Allow-Origin headers for the response of my application. What I did so far is:

```
public class HeaderInterceptor extends HandlerInterceptorAdapter {

    @Autowired
    private DomainProperties domainProperties;
    @Override
    public boolean preHandle(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Object handler)
            throws Exception {
        List<String> domainList= domainProperties.getDomainMap().values().stream().collect(Collectors.toList());
        domainList.stream().forEach(domain -> response.addHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", domain));
        return super.preHandle(request, response, handler);
    }
```

but the problem is I received back a **null** *domainProperties* object, therefore a NullPointerException is thrown here.

Can anyone explain me why did I get a **null** *domainProperties* object here? and how to resolve this problem. Thank you in advanced!

Comment: Annotate HeaderInterceptor class with @Component

Comment: Hi @HemantPatel, I did as you suggested but I still got null domainProperties object

Comment: domainProperties can't be null, because it is autowired (`@Autowired` has `required` attribute `true` by default.) It means this class is not getting created. Add this class (or its package) to `ComponentScan` or `SpringBootApplication`

Comment: (Not so) Wild guess you are doing `new HeaderInterceptor` inside an `addInterceptors` method. Which makes the `HeaderInterceptor` not a bean but just a a created object. Put the creation in a `@Bean` annotated method and use that from inside the `addInterceptors` method.

Comment: hi @M.Deinum, yes you are right, in my _addInterceptors_ method I created new HeaderInterceptor object to add it to the Interceptor: _registry.addInterceptor(new HeaderInterceptor)_ . But I really do not get your solution, is it meaning that I have to put the creation of new HeaderInterceptor in a @Bean, something like: 
`@Bean 
public HeaderInterceptor createHeaderInterceptor(){
return new HeaderInterceptor();
}`
and then use this method in my _registry.addInterceptor(createHeaderInterceptor())_ method?

Comment: exactly that ... That makes the `HeaderInterceptor` a spring managed bean and as such will get auto wired.

Comment: @M.Deinum, sorry Deinum to disturb you again but after changing as you suggest, I still got null pointer exception here :(

Comment: Then you still aren't using the Spring Managed. An `@Autowired` field simply cannot be `null` because the application will fail to start if the auto wiring cannot be fulfilled. So you still must be using a different instance then the spring managed instance.